# random selection on XDF

Tags: r, random, revolution-r

I have tried a lot of alternatives, including the one we can find on Revo website

```
xform <- function(data) { 
    data$.rxRowSelection <- as.logical(rbinom(nr, 1 , 0.5))
    return(data)
}
rxDataStep(inData = "two_vars.xdf", outFile = "testSample",
           transformFunc = xform , overwrite = TRUE)
```

when `nr` is `info$numRows` from `rxGetInfo("two_vars.xdf")`

```
rxDataStep(inData = "two_vars.xdf", outFile = "testSample",
           rowSelection = as.logical(rbinom(nr, 1, 0.5)), overwrite = TRUE)
```

> ERROR: The sample data set for the analysis has no variables.
>   Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
>      std::exception

thanks for helping !

Comment: What is `info$numRows`?

Comment: `info <- rxGetInfo("two_vars.xdf")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
xform <- function(data) { 
    data$.rxRowSelection <- as.logical(rbinom(.rxNumRows, 1 , 0.5))
    return(data)
}
rxDataStep(inData = "two_vars.xdf", outFile = "testSample",
           transformFunc = xform , overwrite = TRUE)
```

Or equivalently:

```
rxDataStep(inData = "two_vars.xdf", outFile = "testSample",
           rowSelection = as.logical(rbinom(.rxNumRows, 1 , 0.5)), 
           overwrite = TRUE)
```

I think there were two issues with what you were doing.

1. You were passing total number of rows and you would need number of rows in that particular chunk. (not the cause of your current error)
2. You need to pass objects via `transformObjects` into the transform environment to use them.

Comment: this works great thanks !
For my understanding `.rxNumRos` returns the number of rows in the actual chunk ?

Comment: That is correct.  It is detailed in the help file `?rxTransform`.